# Why one of the terms disappeared from the equation

Tags: calculus, simple-functions

Right now I was reading about the Landau o notation and I found an exercise which I couldn't understand. Why did $(1/2)x$ disappear from the equation:
$$
x^2+o(x^2)-\frac {1}{2}x^2 + o(x^2)+3x+o(x)+o(x^2) = 3x+o(x)
$$
Thanks for any possible answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this equation is written as $x\to 0$, in which case $-\frac{1}{2}x^2=o(x)$.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks. I couldn't understand why:)

Comment: By the definition, $\frac{1}{2}x^2=o(x)$ since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2}x=0$.